# want cumulative sum of a column extracting particular time frame in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame

```
Date_TimeStamp       value      people
20200203 09:00:00     2.4       100
20200203 10:00:00     3         40
20200203 10:30:00     2.1       300
20200203 11:00:00     4         500
20200203 01:00:00     3.7       300
20200203 03:00:00     3.5       200
```

I want to extract the time when the value is **max** i.e. 4 at 11:00:00
and **cumulative sum** of no of people till that time i.e.   100 + 40 +300 +500 = 940

Answer (score 1):

Get all rows by [`Series.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html), then use for `people` column `sum` or `cumsum` and select last row by position by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
s = df.loc[:df['value'].idxmax()].assign(people = lambda x: x['people'].sum()).iloc[-1]
#same output
#s = df.loc[:df['value'].idxmax()].assign(people = lambda x: x['people'].cumsum()).iloc[-1]
print (s)
Date_TimeStamp    20200203 11:00:00
value                             4
people                          940
Name: 3, dtype: object
```